# When subclassing in iOS, is itsafe to change the type of a property to a subclass of that property?

Tags: ios, properties, subclass

If I have a `UIViewController` subclass (`MNIViewController`) with a property called match - itself a subclass of `NSObject` (`MNISportMatch`).

Now if I make a subclass of the `MNIViewController` (let's say, `MNIFootballViewController`) I'd also make a subclass of the `MNISportMatch` class called `MNIFootballSportMatch`. In `MNIFootballViewController` is it safe to redefine the match property as being a `MNIFootballSportMatch` object instead of a `MNISportMatch` one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the attributes and methods of a superclass are also in the subclass. So if MNIFootballSportMatch is simply a sublcass of MNISportMatch I think it's perfectly safe.